# Delete lines found in file with many lines

Tags: python, excel, file, io

I have an Excel file (.xls) with many lines (1008), and I'm looking for lines that have anything with 2010.

For example, there is a line that contains 01/06/2010, so this line would be deleted, leaving the cell blank.

[image]

For this example, all of these would be deleted. I tried at least reading the file, but I got an ugly error:

```
def Pesquisar():
    nomeArquivo = open('D:/file.xls', 'r')
    for palavraArquivo in nomeArquivo.readlines():
        print palavraArquivo
```

Result:

```
ÐÏà¡±
```

Comment: What are you using to load your excel file, or are you just using python's open()? .xls files cannot be read directly as strings since they are a binary, proprietary format...

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly read an excel file since it's not a standard text file.  You need to use a third party library such as [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd).  Another option would be to export the xls file as a csv file or tab delimited format and then parse them as a text file with python.

Comment: I'm looking at this package, but I do not understand much. Export the file is an easier method?

Comment: @crf_h0m3r: It would probably more straight forward if you don't have a lot of files to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Excel files use a special format that doesn't lend itself to plain text parsing.

This discussion might point you in the right direction, as far as libraries for handling .xls formats go: [Reading/parsing Excel (xls) files with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942889/reading-parsing-xls-files-with-python)