# Found determinated string and delete cell

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I created this topic ( [Delete lines found in file with many lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746845/delete-lines-found-in-file-with-many-lines) ) and they suggested using the package "xlrd". I used and got interact with the file, but could not compare the contents of the cell with some string.
Here's my code:

```
import xlrd
arquivo = xlrd.open_workbook('/media/IRREMOVIVEL/arquivo.xls',)
planilha = arquivo.sheet_by_index(0)


def lerPlanilha():
    for i in range(planilha.ncols):
        if (planilha.cell(8,9) == "2010"):
                print 'it works =>'
                break
    else:
            print 'not works'
                break    

lerPlanilha()
```

But I got error: **not works**
Sorry for duplicate, maybe, and bad english.

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself wrong, I want to compare a string with a given cell, if the data is equal, it will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

xlrd.sheet.Sheet.cell method returns xlrd.sheet.Cell instance, which represents cell with value stored in it's value attribute. So something like sheet.cell(x,y).value should work.

And about deleting - you can't modify document using xlrd, you should use xlwt for writing excel, and xlutils for reading, modifying and writing document. A little intense in googling gives you something like http://www.python-excel.org/