# Python library for handling Excel files (xls | xlsx)

Tags: python, excel

I need a python library that could read and write Excel files with all formats (i.e xls and xlsx).

I'm new to python and I was using Java before. In Java I was using [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library and it was perfect. I need a python library with the same functionality if possible.

Comment: Yup, all libraries I've found support either xls or xlsx, but not both :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading/parsing xls files with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942889/reading-parsing-xls-files-with-python)

Comment: That's because xls is a BIFF file, while xlsx is an Office Open XML format file.  Read http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-xls-and-xlsx/

Comment: @Maulwurfn It's not a duplicate question. The question you've mentioned requires xls only. And I need a library that could handle both. POI library in Java have two main classes; HSSFWorkbook for dealing with xls format, and XFFSWorkbook for dealing with xlsx. I hope to find a python library with the same capability

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread hasn't been active in a while, but I thought it would be nice to add an answer here since I made a new solution to this problem.

I had this same issue so I went ahead and created a small library that includes **python-excel** (xlrd, xlwt) and **openpyxl** within it. You can find it here: https://github.com/camyoung1234/spreadsheet

Then to use it you type the exact same code as openpyxl, except you replace `openpyxl` with `spreadsheet`. When you load and save files it looks at the extension and determines which library to use for handling it.

To install it just download it, extract it, rename the folder `spreadsheet-master` to `spreadsheet` and place it in `PythonXX/Lib/site-packages/` (I've only tested with Python 2.7 but it should work with others)

The `README` has a few examples to help you get started.

Comment: :-  I got this error "from spreadsheet.openpyxl.shared.compat.odict import OrderedDict
ImportError: No module named odict"

Answer (score 2):

Python excel looks like a go: http://www.python-excel.org/

Also OpenPyXl may have the features you need: http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/

Comment: python-excel deals with xls only, and openpyxl deals with xlsx only :(

Comment: Looks like you will need to use both libraries.