# How to Switch between programs with selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a code in python with selenium-crhomedriver. The code open a windows on a specific page where download a excel file, later the code open the excel file, it go to a specific line and copy a value from the sheet.
I need to return to the page and paste the value that copied from excel file on a input field on the page.

I tried with pyautogui simulating the movement but in certain cases i have errors because in occasions i have more than 3 windows open.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import pyautogui
import webbrowser
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
path_excel = r"\Macro_Boletín_Concursal.xlsm"
url = 'http://www.boletinconcursal.cl/boletin/procedimientos'
chrome_path =r"path"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="rut"]""")
driver.get("http://www.boletinconcursal.cl/boletin/procedimientos")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="btnRegistro"]/span[2]""").click()
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'd')
os.popen(path_excel)
time.sleep(7)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
```

In this part i need to go back to the page and later execute this part of code:

```
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a') #highlight
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v') #paste
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="btnBuscarPublicacion"]/span[2]""").click()
```

Then i need a code to move between the excel file and the chromedriver or move from the chromedriver to the excel indifferently.

Comment: You might consider a python library for reading excel files... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752527/python-library-for-handling-excel-files-xls-xlsx

Answer (score 1):

Mac and Windows have keyboard short cuts that can help with switching between windows.

```
elem.send_keys(Keys.ALT, Keys.ESCAPE) #for Windows
elem.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, '~') # for Mac
```

You can also use pyautogui and use the hotkey function. Simply use the same hotkey as shown above.

EDIT:

elem must be a defined webdriver.element. Simply find any webelement by id, classname, xpath, etc. and run the send_keys method on that element as show above.

Comment: when i try to return to chromedriver with pyautogui i have this error: elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
NameError: name 'elem' is not defined