# Is there a way to write to the first empty line in Xlsx writer in Python?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Here is some example xlsxwriter code to write into the worksheet:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')
worksheet.write('A2', 'World', bold)
```

What may be noticed immediately is the cell to write must always be specified. Is there a way to write to the next empty cell, or perhaps a workaround to write to an empty cell? Say I wanted to write to our next empty cell no matter where in column A it was. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

A naive approach would expect something like read the values of the cells till you find an empty one and then write there, but [this is not actually possible with XlsxWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490422/is-it-possible-to-read-data-from-an-excel-sheet-in-python-using-xlsxwriter-if-s).

It looks like you need to keep track of the cells where you are writing or, if you are writing in a file which already contains info, you need to find another solution like [these, suggested in the XlsxWriter documentation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/alternatives.html).

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding from the question, the ask is that we would to leave first line empty in the excel file.

I am not sure about my understanding of this question as the code was unexpectedly very easy, please try below:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('A2', 'India is Great')
workbook.close()
```

Please feel free to add your comments here, I can try to provide some solution/alternate in case I missed anything here.