# array form : excel sheet data to python in numpy array form

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need your help to transfer data to array form shape.
I know how to import excel sheet to  python using this

```
Data = pd.read_excel('filename.xls',sheetname='1',header=None)
```

But when this Data in python, it is not in the numpy array form. cz later I want use this data like array in numpy.

can you help me (I am new in python programming )

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [Reading/parsing Excel (xls) files with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943487/149076) I'd suggest looking at `xlrd` from [www.python-excel.org](http://www.python-excel.org/)