# How to download a .xls into a Python object via FTP with Python ftplib

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, ftp

I am new to Python, so forgive me if I am asking a wrong question. I have a .xls that I would like to ftp and save it as a Python object. Currently, I am taking an awkward approach where [Step 1] I first ftp the file and save it as .txt (I know .xls->.txt is a bad idea!), and then [Step 2] open and save that .txt file in Python shell. That is,

Step 1:

```
## Import the necessary module
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('webftp.vancouver.ca')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('OpenData/xls')
filename = 'new_food_vendor_locations.xls'
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open('myLovelyNewFile.txt', 'w').write)
ftp.quit()
```

This allows me to create a new file 'myLovelyNewFile.txt' in my current directly. In my Python shell, I have:

Step 2:

```
myLovelyPython = open('myLovelyNewFile.txt','r')
for line in myLovelyPython.readlines():
     print line
myLovelyPython.close()
```

Although Python can run all these command lines, the printed lines do not have correct inputs due to the forceful conversion from xls to txt. Furthermore, I would like to save the ftp-ed object directly as some python object (rather than first saving it as .txt outside Python). Is there easy solution to this problem?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to download the .xls as .xls and save it as .xls? You can then load the xls using one of the solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942889/reading-parsing-excel-xls-files-with-python

Comment: @jcoppens Like you say, I tried the following commands: 
ftp = FTP('webftp.vancouver.ca');
ftp.login();
ftp.cwd('OpenData/xls');
filename = 'new_food_vendor_locations.xls';     workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename); ftp.quit();
 However this gives me an error statement that "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'new_food_vendor_locations.xls'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was looking for a way to directly purse the ftp-ed excel file into Python object, if I allows saving the excel file in my directory and re-read it again, the following works:

```
ftp = FTP('webftp.vancouver.ca')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('OpenData/xls')
filename = 'new_food_vendor_locations.xls'
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open('myLovelyNewFile.xls', 'w').write)
ftp.quit()
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('myLovelyNewFile.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Query_vendor_food')
num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
curr_row = -1
while curr_row < num_rows:
    curr_row += 1
    row = worksheet.row(curr_row)
    print row
```

(I thank @jacoppens for his advice.)