# CParserError: Error tokenizing data

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I'm having some trouble reading a csv file

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Data_Matches_tekha.csv', skiprows=2)
```

I get

> pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 526, saw 5

and when I add `sep=None` to `df` I get another error

> Error: line contains NULL byte

I tried adding `unicode='utf-8'`, I even tried CSV reader and nothing works with this file

the csv file is totally fine, I checked it and i see nothing wrong with it

Here are the errors I get:

[image]

Comment: Can you ignore bad lines looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your actual code, the line is:

```
>>> pandas.read_csv("Data_Matches_tekha.xlsx", sep=None)
```

You are trying to read an Excel file, and not a plain text CSV which is why things are not working.

Excel files (xlsx) are in a special binary format which cannot be read as simple text files (like CSV files).

You need to either convert the Excel file to a CSV file (note - if you have multiple sheets, each sheet should be converted to its own csv file), and then read those.

You can use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) or you can use a library like `xlrd` which is designed to read the binary format of Excel files; see [Reading/parsing Excel (xls) files with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942889/reading-parsing-excel-xls-files-with-python) for for more information on that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) instead `read_csv` if `Excel` file:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Data_Matches_tekha.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error when I used to_csv to write some data and then read it in another script. I found an easy solution without passing by pandas' read function, it's a package named ***Pickle***.

You can download it by typing in your terminal

```
pip install pickle
```

Then you can use for writing your data (first) the code below

```
import pickle 

with open(path, 'wb') as output:
pickle.dump(variable_to_save, output)
```

And finally import your data in another script using

```
import pickle 

with open(path, 'rb') as input:
data = pickle.load(input)
```

Note that if you want to use, when reading your saved data, a different python version than the one in which you saved your data, you can precise that in the writing step by using `protocol=x` with x corresponding to the version (2 or 3) aiming to use for reading.

I hope this can be of any use.