# Beautiful Soup Tree Backward Navigation

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

[Shell screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKR4l.jpg)

Hello:

I am a Python neophyte so apologies in advance if this question is too easy. I’ve been searching like crazy for an answer but cannot seem to find an example that is applicable to my case.

In Python 3 running Beautiful Soup, I am trying set my html tree reference as a specific href and then scrape the 6 preceding numerical values from the url below.

```
url = 'http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_sum_sndw_dcus_nus_w.htm'
```

My reason for starting from the `href` tag is that it is the only reference in the html which stays the same and is not repeated again.

In my example, I would like to start at the `href` tag:

```
href="./hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&amp;s=W_EPOOXE_YIR_NUS_MBBLD&amp;f=W"
```

Then scape the individual contents from the six `"td=class"` tags preceding that tag:

```
936, 934, 919,957, 951, 928.
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: looks like you can get the page data in .xls format http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/xls/PET_SUM_SNDW_DCUS_NUS_W.xls may be simpler to parse that?

Comment: Thanks. I saw that but was just curious if anyone had tried something similar in Python.

Comment: you can also [parse .xls in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942889/reading-parsing-excel-xls-files-with-python). However if you want to do it with BeautifulSoup.. i assume you are trying to extract all the data from the html table? or is it just the row associated with that specific href?

Comment: Just parts of the data from the table. The rows would vary based on a couple of specific hrefs.

Answer (score 1):

First select the anchor using the *href*, then find the six previous td's:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_sum_sndw_dcus_nus_w.htm'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content,"html.parser")
anchor = soup.select_one("a[href=./hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=W_EPOOXE_YIR_NUS_MBBLD&f=W]")
data = [td.text for td in anchor.find_all_previous("td","DataB", limit=6)]
```

If we run the code, you can see we get text from the previous six td's:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   ...: import requests
   ...: url = 'http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_sum_sndw_dcus_nus_w.htm'
   ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content,"html.parser")
   ...: anchor = soup.select_one("a[href=./hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=W_EPOOX
   ...: E_YIR_NUS_MBBLD&f=W]")
   ...: data = [td.text for td in anchor.find_all_previous("td","DataB", limit=6
   ...: )]
   ...: 

In [2]: data
Out[2]: ['934', '919', '957', '951', '928', '139']
```

That does not quite get there as there as there are two different classes for the td's *Current2* and *DataB* sdo we can use the parent of the anchor which will be a td itself:

```
In [5]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   ...: import requests
   ...: url = 'http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_sum_sndw_dcus_nus_w.htm'
   ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content,"html.parser")
   ...: anchor_td = soup.find("a", href="./hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=W_EPOOXE_Y
   ...: IR_NUS_MBBLD&f=W").parent
   ...: data = [td.text for td in anchor_td.find_all_previous("td", limit=6)]
   ...: 

In [6]: data
Out[6]: ['936', '934', '919', '957', '951', '928']
```

Now we get exactly what we want.

Lastly we could get the *grandparent* of the *anchor* i.e the main *td* then use a select using the the both the class names in our *select*:

```
href = "./hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=W_EPOOXE_YIR_NUS_MBBLD&f=W"
grandparent = soup.find("a", href=href).parent.parent
data = [td.text for td in grandparent.select("td.Current2,td.DataB")]
```

Again data gives us the same output.

Comment: Thanks a million gentlemen, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the file is a number of tables, the one you are interested in being the second. Since you know the value of the `href` attribute you want to match on, one way to access the parts you need would be to iterate over the table rows, first of all checking in the `href` value is the one you want.