# How to get data from one Excel sheet and write on another Excel Sheet using Python?

Tags: python, regex, excel

**How to get data from one Excel sheet and write on another Excel Sheet using Python?**

**Eg:** 
   I have Excel name Original Sheet with come contents i need to read those contents and write on another Excel name Copy Sheet By Using Python.

**Note :** *Read and Write both should be done by using Python Code*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading/parsing Excel (xls) files with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942889/reading-parsing-excel-xls-files-with-python)

Comment: Is it possible to read the data from specific Column of the Excel and Write to another Excel sheet using Python..in that only they mentioned about read/parse Excel with python only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pandas library to do this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('original_sheet.xlsx')
df.to_excel('copy_sheet.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks.! If i need to need to read only the specify column from original sheet and write that to copy sheet..is it possible..if so? how?

Comment: For this you can use the parameter `usecols` from `pandas.read_excel`.
I suggest you have a look at `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html`

Comment: Link is Not working...It shows 404 Error.!  **@Marine**

Comment: Weird it works for me ... just google `pandas read_excel`, you'll find the documentation