# Pandas read_excel returns PendingDeprecationWarning

Tags: python, pandas, import, openpyxl, xlrd

I have been importing Excel files as Pandas data frames using the `read_excel` function with no apparent issues so far. However, I just realized that after some recent updates I'm getting the below warning:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py:266: PendingDeprecationWarning: This method will be removed in future versions.  Use 'tree.iter()' or 'list(tree.iter())' instead.
>
> for elem in self.tree.iter() if Element_has_iter else self.tree.getiterator():
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py:312: PendingDeprecationWarning: This method will be removed in future versions.  Use 'tree.iter()' or 'list(tree.iter())' instead.
>
> for elem in self.tree.iter() if Element_has_iter else self.tree.getiterator():

Searching the internet, it seems that the `xlrd` is being replaced by `openpyxl`. Now my questions are:

- What does this warning mean and what should I do?
- Is my data import safe at this moment? Do I have to worry that something not working properly?
- What are those `tree.iter()` or `list(tree.iter())` methods? and what they are replacing?
- Is there another method to import Excel files as pandas data frames without getting this warning already?
- Should I report a bug or issues somewhere? Where?

my environment is:

- macOS Mojave 10.14.6
- Python 3.7.6
- Pandas 1.0.0
- xlrd 1.2.0

Comment: xlrd is no longer maintained, use openpyxl instead.

Comment: @CharlieClark sure, but how? is there any other command within pandas? or a way to tell `read_excel` which engine should it use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your data import is "safe" at the moment.  To get rid of the warning and future-proof your code, try:

```
pd.read_excel(filename, engine="openpyxl")
```

or put this at the start of your script:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("xlsx", "openpyxl")
```

Comment: Is this a new feature?

Comment: The only thing constant with Python is change.  With the possible exception of `xlrd`!

Comment: I wish that `pd.set_option` existed, but after looking through the source I don't see it as of now.

Comment: [set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option) does exist, but at least as of version 1.1.3, `io.excel.xlsx.reader` is ignored in the code. The only answer that seems to work is to pass `engine="openpyxl"` to `pd.read_excel`.