# I am unable to open the excel file with pandas,

Tags: excel, pandas, data-science

it displays the following error
[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX0wG.png)
well i have already tried with diffrent file but it doesnt work

```
data1=pd.read_excel('second.xlsx',sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried passing `engine="openpyxl"` argument?

P.S this is where I found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50815107

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: nope i havent tried yet, i will try it now