# Fetch some specific rows in python excel

Tags: python, excel

I have a excel file which contains many rows

I want to fetch some rows and columns where row starts with 1396 to 1577.

What is the python code for that?

Pls note: Do not use pandas

i dont know the approach ,  can anyone send code?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the code that you currently have? It would help us to better match your specific use case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading/parsing Excel (xls) files with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942889/reading-parsing-excel-xls-files-with-python)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.